# How does browser generate symmetric key during SSL handshake

Tags: ssl, random, browser-security

I have a small confusion on SSL handshake between browser and server in a typical https web scenario:

What I have understood so far is that in the process of SSL handshake, client (browser in this case) encrypts a randomly selected symmetric key with the public key (certificate received from server). This is sent back to the server, server decrypts it (symmetric key) with the private key. This symmetric key is now used during rest of the session to encrypt/decrypt the messages at both the ends. One of main reasons to do so is given as faster encryption using symmetric keys.

**Questions**

1) How does browser pick and generates this "randomly" selected symmetric key?

2) Do developers (or/and browser users) have control on this mechanism of generating symmetric keys?

Comment: The client does not generate the session key; does not encrypt it; and does not transmit it. The session key is derived via a key agreement protocol. Your description is basically incorrect. Your question is founded on a false assumption.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Here](http://www.moserware.com/2009/06/first-few-milliseconds-of-https.html) is a very good description of how HTTPS connection establishment works. I will provide summary how session key is acquired by both parties (client and server), this process is known as "a key agreement protocol", here how it works:

1. The client generates the 48 byte “pre-master secret” random value.
2. The client pads these bytes with random data to make the input equal to 128 bytes.
3. The client encrypts it with server's public key and sends it to the server.
4. Then master key is produced by both parties in following manner:

   ```
   master_secret = PRF(
      pre_master_secret, 
      "master secret", 
      ClientHello.random + ServerHello.random
   )
   ```

> The PRF is the “Pseudo-Random Function” that’s also defined in the
>   spec and is quite clever. It combines the secret, the ASCII label, and
>   the seed data we give it by using the keyed-Hash Message
>   Authentication Code (HMAC) versions of both MD5 and SHA-1 hash
>   functions. Half of the input is sent to each hash function. It’s
>   clever because it is quite resistant to attack, even in the face of
>   weaknesses in MD5 and SHA-1. This process can feedback on itself and
>   iterate forever to generate as many bytes as we need.
>
> Following this procedure, we obtain a 48 byte “master secret”.

Comment: The client does not generate the session key; does not encrypt it; and does not transmit it. The session key is derived via a key agreement protocol.

Comment: @EJP you are right, my answer was completely incorrect, I rewrote it. Please check it and tell me if you think it is better now.

Comment: @user207421, could you share more information on how session key generated?

Comment: @Xilang check my updated answer, I corrected it based on user207421 remark.

Comment: _The client generates the 48 byte “pre-master secret” random value._ The client has to do this for every server? Is that right? Otherwise if my browser shares its secret with Facebook, then Facebook could potentially decrypt my communications with Twitter (if it installs something locally) because they're using the same key.

Comment: @honey it must be generated for every session, not just every server.

Comment: oh. Yeah that makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from a this great video on network video, [minute 1:18:07](https://youtu.be/E03gh1huvW4?t=4687)

> Well where do you get randomness on your computer because your
>   computer is a deterministic device?
>
> Well it collects entropies like your mouse stroke movements, your key
>   stroke movements and the timing of your hard disk, it tries to collect
>   all that randomness from the universe into a pull so that it can generate random keys just for **one connection [this session]**. And if that randomness is broken and its happened many times
>   in the last 30 years, then none of this works. If the adversary can
>   figure what your randomness can be then they can guess your keys. So use good randomness.

Note: the keys are created **per session**.

Comment: The video was soooooo good. It answers many many questions I had about network security. Once I started watching I just couldn't stop myself from watching more. The instructor answers every random question that any non-security expert programmer wants to know of. I'll definitely go back and watch it again.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question that was asked.

Comment: Mentioned youtube video is not available anymore :(

Comment: @user2306856 bummer. I searched for it and couldn't find it.