# How to distribute public key in asymmetric encryption algorithms?

Tags: java, encryption, encryption-asymmetric

There are two keys in asymmetric encryption algorithm

- public key and
- private key

For the concept of client and server, it need to public key on server side to decrypt client's message.

So my question is *how can we share public key between client and server?*

I am using JAVA, so if your example contains java code this will ok for me, or if any pictorial info, this will very ok.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you mean that the **private** key on the server decrypts the client's message, right? Why not just install an SSL certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the client hasn't met the server before, so he doesn't *know* what public key to expect, one must use a third party intermediary to validate the identities involved. In P2P scenarios, you have what are called "[key signing parties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_signing_party)", where people exchange public keys through meeting face-to-face.

If the people already know eachother, then, even through an insecure channel, you can use algorithms like [Diffie-Hellman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) to exchange your identities, which you can validate against the information you already had about the identity of that person.

In a common HTTPS scenario, the client may not already know the server, but the server presents a certificate, validated by a mutually-trusted third party, that acknowledges his identity. For instance, Paypal might present you with a certificate that says "VeriSign agrees I am who I say I am.", and if you trust VeriSign, this "web of trust" as it's called means you'll trust Paypal are who they says they are.

In your client-server scenario, the server needs both its private and public key - the public key is used for encrypting the messages going back to the client, and the private key is used to decrypt the messages the client is sending to him.

The server doesn't usually know who the user is (cryptographically speaking), the client may make a new certificate and public/private keypair for each request it sends. A way to change this is detailed in [this IBM article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-SSL_client_authentication/). What ends up happening in usual HTTPS scenarios is a mixture of private and public key encryptions; you can read more about that in [this related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936071/how-does-browser-generate-symmetric-key-during-ssl-handshake).

Good luck!

Comment: That's quite the explanation.

Comment: @Federico Lebrón can you give me some links?

Comment: Links to what, specifically? (Note that the colored words in my post are all links, "key signing parties", "Diffie-Hellman", "this IBM article", and "this related SO post"). If you want, here's an implementation of key exchange using [Diffie Hellman in Java](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/ImplementingtheDiffieHellmankeyexchange.htm).